# Creality slicer filling in holes that aren't supposed to

Tags: creality-ender-3

I'm pretty new to 3D printing and I made my own file in Blender. I exported it to Creality slicer, printed it, and it was filling the holes that aren't supposed to be filled.

It's supposed to look like this:

[image: Screenshot of rendered model in Creality slicer]

but ends up looking like this:

[image: Screenshot of rendered model in Creality slicer with hole filled]

I looked around and saw that it might be broken or something so if anyone knows how to fix that Heres my stl file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1auVJb8xFT_33rf3gDXCzf5Hz6K9TvfSv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I don't use that slicer, but there are issues with the STL file, when I fixed them and sliced it looked ok.

So I suggest to fix your STL first. Lots of programs including blender have tools to help with that. Or you could use a free online stl repair.